# Grafana to query through Amazon Athena failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-athena

I am trying to query in Grafana using Amazon Athena as a source.

### Experiment 1

First, I created an Amazon Athena workgroup called `xx-workgroup` with query output location set to a S3 path. I can confirm I can query through Amazon Athena web UI directly:

[image]

Then I added Amazon Athena as source in Grafana, and it successfully connect. It shows database and workgroup correctly. Also, I set up Amazon Athena query output location:

[image]

However, when I query, I got error:

> error querying the database: error executing query: InvalidRequestException: No output location provided. An output location is required either through the Workgroup result configuration setting or as an API input. { RespMetadata: { StatusCode: 400, RequestID: "b8ba431e-8668-4049-b38a-d24672107df8" }, AthenaErrorCode: "INVALID_INPUT", Message_: "No output location provided. An output location is required either through the Workgroup result configuration setting or as an API input." }

[image]

### Experiment 2

I also tried to set the query output location at Amazon Athena workgroup level to override client side's query output location:

[image]

But still got same error in Grafana. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Pregz I haven't. But if I found a way, I will post here. Thanks!

Comment: Also interested in any solutions on this - can't seem to get Grafana Cloud + AWS Athena to work at all..

Answer (score -1):

Got the very same experience with this. Managed to get it working by setting up the "Location of query result" in the Workgroup configuration. And also selected "Override client-side settings". Depending on your setup, you might want to define a separate workgroup to be used by Grafana. One thing that I will certainly do is to configure data usage alert and data limit on it... ;-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).